# how to convert to .CSV encoding UNIX to encoding dos/win with PHP

Tags: php, unix, csv, encoding, utf-8

I generate a .csv encoding UNIX file from PHP, these file need's to read in Java with encoding UTF-8 dos/win (i see this encoding with note++), I have two ways to resolve this, once that is generate the file with PHP in encoding UTF-8 dos/win or read this file with Java whit UTF-8 or UNIX encodig. Can you help me? I don't no what to do! I try generate the .csv encoding UTF-8 with PHP but I can't. Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us your php code ?

Comment: $renglon[47].PHP_EOL;
 //$fields[]="\r\n";
 //if($j < 22000)
 $caracteres = array(",","\"");
 $renglonmejorado = str_replace($caracteres, "", $renglon);          .....................................................................................................................//echo "preparando archivo de salida.....<br />";
$fp = fopen('../files/example.csv', 'w');
//echo "escribiendo en el archivo.....<br />";
foreach ($fields as $campos){
 fputcsv($fp, $campos);         ....   I don't it helps @bigben3333 thank you

Comment: arg, ... Please add your code to your question! ;-) and use the `{}` tool at the top right of the `edit` box to keep the format. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line break to be compatible with DOS/WIN must be :

```
$line.="\r\n"
```

in php.

And to be UTF8 it depends you data source.